# Backbone.js remove event not triggering

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following view, where I'm trying to bind the click event to a delete button, but it doesn't seem to be triggering anything.  Not getting any errors in console, it just doesn't seem to be binding the "click" event.

The span.delete element is deeply nested within a bunch of other elements, not sure if that matters, I've tried it as a direct child element as well, but still no go.

```
var ListRow = Backbone.View.extend(
{
    events:
    {
        'click span.delete': 'remove'
    },

    initialize: function()
    {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'unrender', 'remove');

        this.model.bind('remove', this.unrender);
    },

    render: function()
    {
        this.el = _.template($('#tpl-sTableList_' + key + 'Row').html());

        return this;
    },

    unrender: function()
    {
        $(this.el).fadeOut();
    },

    remove: function()
    {
        this.model.destroy();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, it was because I was only setting the el object, but not rendering it, so instead of:

```
this.el =
```

should be

```
$(this.el).html();
```

Otherwise all works as expected.

Comment: Doesn't `this.$el` exists? so it should be `this.$el.html()`

Answer (score 2):

There is no default `remove` event on a model, there is only a remove event coming from the collection, so if you want to remove a view when the model gets removed from the collection, it's probably better to put a

```
this.collection.bind('remove', this.onRemove, this);
```

in your ListView (as I assume you're using a ListView and a ListItemView based on your example) and then your `onRemove` method passes the model as an argument so you can find the view that's associated with it.

Comment: Still can't get this to work, I would think that at least the remove function would be called when I click the span.delete, but doesn't seem to be getting triggered.